# iOS view visibility gone

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, view, swift4

I am new to iOS development.I want to toggle (hide/visible) a subview from parent view.In android there is a way to hide the visibility to gone.

In android

```
subView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

In iOS

```
subView.removeFromSuperview()
```

when i use above function it remove subViewConstraints and mess up my scroll view constraints.

```
topsubView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomSubView.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
```

when i use the above code it works fine and hide subView.but when i want to make subView visible,it is not showing the subView.

```
topsubView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomSubView.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = false
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Hope you understand my problem.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use `subView.isHidden = true`

Comment: Thanks.but i want to remove the space of the subView also. 
 subView.isHidden is not removing the space

Comment: see my solution

Comment: Then you should use UIStackView and add subviews. It hides the space also when its subview is hidden

Comment: Set your view height constraint and set it 0 when u want to remove space.

Comment: Hi, Buddy no one understands your exact question is, As I have worked on both, You need to play with constraint outlet in ios to achieve Android functioning. iOS Does not support automatically like Android native support on visibility `GONE` & `VISIBLE`

Comment: Thanks mukesh and RajeshKumar....using stack viewUIStackView is also working fine

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As I have worked on both iOS & Android, You need to play with constraint outlet in ios to achieve Android functioning. iOS Does not support automatically like Android native support on visibility `GONE` & `VISIBLE`

You need to hook the `outlet` of particular `constraint`(it may vertical/horizontal/height) you need to set it to `0` & need to manage your UI.

**To Hide:**

```
self.viewYourConstraint.constant = 0
self.yourView.hidden = true
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

**To Show:**

```
self.viewYourConstraint.constant = 100//your constant value
self.yourView.hidden = false
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

> Note: If other constraints will be affected because of the update to the constraint above, the following must also need to be called:

```
self.yourView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
```

Comment: Is the hidden part necessary when you are setting the height constraint to 0?

Comment: Thats how it work in iOS, gone feature is not available on IOS. Somehow even you remove view from superview then you will have to create that view again then..

Comment: Well I have similar code without using `self.yourView.hidden = true` and everything works fine since I am making the view's height constraint equal to 0 when I want it hidden.

Comment: Yes, thats true, But the best practices in the iOS is we should have to make view hidden as well.

Answer (score 26):

Try this extension:

```
extension UIView {
    
    func visiblity(gone: Bool, dimension: CGFloat = 0.0, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute = .height) -> Void {
        if let constraint = (self.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == attribute}.first) {
            constraint.constant = gone ? 0.0 : dimension
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.isHidden = gone
        }
    }
}
```

How you can use this....

```
@IBOutlet weak var testView: UIView?
@IBAction func testVisibilty(switchbutton: UISwitch) -> Void {
    
    let viewHeight:CGFloat = switchbutton.isOn ? 100 : 0.0
    self.testView?.visiblity(gone: !switchbutton.isOn, dimension: viewHeight)
    
    // set visibility for width constraint
    //let viewWidth:CGFloat = switchbutton.isOn ? 300 : 0.0
    //self.testView?.visiblity(gone: !switchbutton.isOn, dimension: viewWidth, attribute: .width)
  
}
```

Here is result:

[image]

Comment: why properties are  reset by this exension

Answer (score 23):

Maybe you'd prefer this solution

```
extension UIView {

    enum Visibility {
        case visible
        case invisible
        case gone
    }

    var visibility: Visibility {
        get {
            let constraint = (self.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == .height && $0.constant == 0}.first)
            if let constraint = constraint, constraint.isActive {
                return .gone
            } else {
                return self.isHidden ? .invisible : .visible
            }
        }
        set {
            if self.visibility != newValue {
                self.setVisibility(newValue)
            }
        }
    }

    private func setVisibility(_ visibility: Visibility) {
        let constraint = (self.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == .height && $0.constant == 0}.first)

        switch visibility {
        case .visible:
            constraint?.isActive = false
            self.isHidden = false
            break
        case .invisible:
            constraint?.isActive = false
            self.isHidden = true
            break
        case .gone:
            if let constraint = constraint {
                constraint.isActive = true
            } else {
                let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                self.addConstraint(constraint)
                constraint.isActive = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then the usage is:

```
someView.visibility = .visible
someView.visibility = .invisible
someView.visibility = .gone
```

**edit:**

improving capabilities: will work from storyboard (just write: 'visible', 'invisible', 'gone') in the "Visibility State"

**all constraints inside view should be less then a 1000**

```
extension UIView {

    enum Visibility: String {
        case visible = "visible"
        case invisible = "invisible"
        case gone = "gone"
    }

    var visibility: Visibility {
        get {
            let constraint = (self.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == .height && $0.constant == 0}.first)
            if let constraint = constraint, constraint.isActive {
                return .gone
            } else {
                return self.isHidden ? .invisible : .visible
            }
        }
        set {
            if self.visibility != newValue {
                self.setVisibility(newValue)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var visibilityState: String {
        get {
            return self.visibility.rawValue
        }
        set {
            let _visibility = Visibility(rawValue: newValue)!
            self.visibility = _visibility
        }
    }

    private func setVisibility(_ visibility: Visibility) {
        let constraints = self.constraints.filter({$0.firstAttribute == .height && $0.constant == 0 && $0.secondItem == nil && ($0.firstItem as? UIView) == self})
        let constraint = (constraints.first)

        switch visibility {
        case .visible:
            constraint?.isActive = false
            self.isHidden = false
            break
        case .invisible:
            constraint?.isActive = false
            self.isHidden = true
            break
        case .gone:
            self.isHidden = true
            if let constraint = constraint {
                constraint.isActive = true
            } else {
                let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                // constraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
                self.addConstraint(constraint)
                constraint.isActive = true
            }
            self.setNeedsLayout()
            self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bravo tqvm. Worked for iOS newbie like me. Thumbs up !

Answer (score 8):

You say you want to hide your subview and remove the space it occupies. If you want to avoid messing with constraints, you can try using stack views:

- Create a `UIStackView` and setup appropriate constraints between the stack view and its parent view;
- Add views to the stack view;
- Now you can toggle the visibility of these views inside the stack view by setting `view.isHidden` to true or false, and the layout will adjust automatically.

Comment: What If the views don't have constant spacing?

Comment: This is the quickest and easiest solution, but maybe is not the best for all cases! @sandpat you just need to set the view inside stack with no fixed size, and two constraints for the top and bottom (or lead and trail) of the views inside this view.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for `view.isHidden = true`. This simply hides the view in place without altering the view hierarchy or constraint mapping. You can subsequently re-show your view . with `view.isHidden = false`.

Comment: Thanks but  i want to remove the space of the subView also